# C# - Accessing preprocessor debug variables inside of [Conditional("DEBUG")] functions

Tags: c#, function, variables, debugging, preprocessor

Example:

```
#if DEBUG
    float testVar;
#endif

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void TestFunc()
{
    testVar = 3;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to access a variable that is within a DEBUG preprocessor if statement. But unfortunately this causes compilation errors in release mode. Is there a way to make this work in release mode **without having to surround every call of TestFunc() with preprocessor if statements**?

Comment: Why not surround the assignment statement with `#if DEBUG`

Comment: I think everything is cool here. What kind of compilation errors do you get?  And are you sure that there is active 'DEBUG' solution configuration?

Comment: @godot "What kind of compilation errors do you get?" If you look closely to the text I wrote: "But unfortunately this causes compilation errors in release mode", I mentioned the errors are in release mode. I want is this to work in both release and debug mode.

Comment: @KlausGütter this is one way, but I would like to avoid having many of these preprocessor statements in my code. In this example that I gave it would work fine, but in more complex examples, where the variables is used in many different places, it gets quite clutterly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a property which has no backing field in the release build:

```
#if DEBUG
    float testVar { get; set; }
#else
    float testVar 
    {
        get { return 0.0F; }
        set { throw NotImpementedException(); }
    }
#endif
```

This makes access to `testVar` syntactically legal but does not consume any per-instance memory.

Comment: That is nice. I just want to wait before I mark your answer, because I want to see if maybe someone else has any other (or better) solution.